# Test case execution fail using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, mockito, slf4j

I am trying to execute test case using mokito framework, but stuck with few error. Below is my code :

```
public interface SaleforceSearchLeadService {
    public String buildSOSL(String email);
}
public class SalesforceLeadSearch1 implements SaleforceSearchLeadService{  
    public SalesforceLeadSearch1(){
    }
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SalesforceLeadSearch1.class);
    public String buildSOSL(String email)
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Company, Status, Email, Age__c FROM LEAD ");
        query.append("WHERE Email = '"+email+"'"); 
        return query.toString();
    }
}
public class SalesforceLeadSearch1Test  {
  @Mock
  private SaleforceSearchLeadService service;
    @Test
    public void testBuildSOSL() {
       SalesforceLeadSearch1 test=new SalesforceLeadSearch1();
       StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
       String email="vivek.k@abc.com";
       query.append("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Company, Status, Email, Age__c FROM LEAD ");
       query.append("WHERE Email = '"+email+"'");
      // assertEquals("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Company, Status, Email, Age__c FROM LEAD WHERE Email = 'vivek.k@abc.com'",service.buildSOSL(email));
        assertEquals("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Company, Status, Email, Age__c FROM LEAD WHERE Email = 'vivek.k@.com'",test.buildSOSL("vivek.k@abc.com"));

    }
}
```

Below is the stack trace :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.ig.igwebcms.services.impl.SalesforceLeadSearch1.<clinit>(SalesforceLeadSearch1.java:40)
    at com.ig.igwebcms.services.test.SalesforceLeadSearch1Test.testBuildSOSL(SalesforceLeadSearch1Test.java:39)
```

Even I tried use of service instance which giving me NPE.

And if I remove Logger from SalesforceLeadSearch1 class its pass the test, don't understand why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is missing one of the SLF4j implementations. Make sure that it is included in your CLASSPATH, or defined in your POM, if you use Maven.

Comment: This exception states this, but its available in maven's POM.If i remove Logger this works. Also if i try something `SalesforceClient client=mock(SalesforceClient.class);` also gives NoClassDefFoundError. No able to mock a class.

Comment: My mistake, I was selecting junit 3, instead of junit 4 at create test wizard.